# MobileMedia Queries width issues

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have a site that I am making responsive to fit any screen size. The problem is on smaller (320px) screens there is some "white space" appearing to the far right of my pages, I can reproduce this on iPhone 5 and BBz10.  Any help is much appreciated!  In my HTML I have declared

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

Inside my CSS files....

```
html{
    font-size:62.5%;
    margin:0;
}

body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#F0F1EC;
    color:#545452;
}
#header{
    background-color:red;
    height:25px;
}


@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 555px) {

  //there is no code related to widths of any element in this media query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the extra white space which causes to slide on right side, you can try adding the following media query..

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
body, html{
max-width:320px;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
}
```